# Where does Havoc Os store update files?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, twrp

I am relatively new in **[HavocOS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-7-pro/development/rom-havoc-os-2-6-t3942337)**.

I am seeing an update has arrived in my OS, it is downloaded already.
But I can't find the files downloaded in the mobile.

I want to manually update with **TWRP** recovery to install the Upgrade.

But where does HavocOs store its downloaded upgrade files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution [***here***](https://forum.xda-developers.com/asus-zenfone-max-pro-m1/development/rom-havoc-os-t3852830/post79863428#post79863428).

> Hold **tap** near the **changelog button** and you'll see an **export option pop up**.
>
> Click on it and it will export zip file in **internal storage** in a folder called ***Updates***

Answer (score -1):

`/data/havoc_updates/` is the location.